# read pdf file from server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf-generation

I am trying to develop android app that can view pdf file from the server. 
I have edited my code. Check it out.

Here the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                //String LinkToPDF = "http://127.0.0.1/joomla/images/appletter.pdf";
                WebView mWebView=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
                mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=nizam.hostingsiteforfree.com/do‌​c_8.pdf");
                setContentView(mWebView);

            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
              }
```

There's no error with that. But it displays this whenever i click the button "read pdf"

"Sorry we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists."

Please help me get rid of this problem. Any help?

Comment: i tried using localhost. it don't work.

Answer (score 1):

While referring localhost from Emulator, use `http://10.0.2.2/` instead of your local ip.
So the change in your code will be

```
String LinkToPDF = "http://10.0.2.2/joomla/images/appletter.pdf";
```

Also, this will work only with Emulator. For real device, you need real server.

**UPDATE:**
I tested your code. Its working only for a real server. Seems like 'google docs' can't access localhost files. So, test using a real server. There are many free hosting sites which you can use for testing purpose.

Joomla is not a server. Joomla is a [content management system (CMS)](http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html). You installed Joomla in your 'localhost', which is only an imitation of server, not a real server.(one of the free hosting site- [freeHosting](http://www.1freehosting.com)). Register on real server(can use free hosting for now), get your own url, and upload pdf to there. Feel free to mail me if you need more details about hosting.

Now, an important part:- **SSL certificate**. Free hostings may not have a valid SSL. So, refer as following:

```
    String LinkToPDF = "http://nizam.hostingsiteforfree.com/doc_8.pdf";
    WebView webview=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final Activity activity = this;
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            Log.d("Nzm", ""+error.getPrimaryError());
             Toast.makeText(activity, "Skipping SSL error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=nizam.hostingsiteforfree.com/doc_8.pdf");
```

Comment: I tried that 10.0.2.2 but still not working. i also tried opening it directly to the pdf url instead of redirecting to google docs but none of this works. I have internet permission also in my manifest. Please help me.

Comment: I really need to do this now. Could you help me find solution for this?

Comment: did you get it? You can test it using: `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=nizam.hostingsiteforfree.com/doc_8.pdf`

Comment: ok. i have joomla web server. I have already logged in to that web server and uploaded the file. How can i fetch it from joomla? That is our choosen web server.

Comment: So, what your url became for the file?

Comment: Before testing your url(except localhost 10.0.2.2) using pgm, paste it in your system browser and check if it is ok.

Comment: what do u mean by pgm?

Comment: and i want to ask what do u mean a real server?Is my joomla not a real server?I'm really confused because i have already uploaded images and pdf to joomla. All i Need is to fetch that pdf to android. What server did you use to test my code?

Comment: I have tried your url.It gave me same response. Sorry response appears instead of the pdf content.

Comment: hey @nizam i tried to paste it in my browser using pgm u told me and it works fine. I really don't know why it's now working in my code both real device and emulator.

Comment: I mean it's not working in my code both real device and emulator.

Comment: this is my email. calrkver3232@gmail.com. I need help from registration.         "Your computer IP address is blocked from registration. If you are using proxy please disable it and try again. Alternatively you can try to register from a different computer or ask your friend to fill a registration form for you."

Comment: i email u in your gmail. just check it because i really need your help. Thanks

Comment: i have already signed up and activated the account. i already have created account. its. healthhelp.hostingsiteforfree.com.

Comment: i hope u will reply me in email. Thanks

Comment: I don't received any message from u. here clarkver3232@gmail.com. Anyway thanks for answering me.